# what is the ... syntax in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Jumping from regular old js with ang1 to ang2 with typescript and redux etc is a heck of a steep climb.

Could anyone offer a simple explanation to the ... syntax? Having come from a php and javascript background this is really new stuff.

http://blog.ng-book.com/introduction-to-redux-with-typescript-and-angular-2/#deleting-an-item-without-mutation shows this as an example with redux:

```
return {
      messages: [
        ...state.messages.slice(0, idx),
        ...state.messages.slice(idx + 1, state.messages.length)
      ]
```

But does anyone have an uber simple example for a complete noob to this area? Feels like i'm going round in circles!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The three dots represent the **rest operator** and it is used to get the
>   arguments list passed to function on invocation and in array
>   destructure. A case when the operator gathers the rest remained after
>   the operation.
>
> The **spread operator** is used for array construction and destructuring,
>   and to fill function arguments from an array on invocation. A case
>   when the operator spreads the array (or iterable object) elements.

You can read more about this [here](https://rainsoft.io/how-three-dots-changed-javascript/).

Comment: This is somehow messed up, spread is never used in destructuring - only in array literals and function calls. Btw, you shouldn't call it an "operator" since technically it isn't one, we prefer the terms "rest parameter" and "spread syntax".